# Magnetic permeability tensor of single crystal iron

Tags: tensor-calculus

It has been reported that single crystal iron's magnetic properties are anisotropic. I want to formulate the permeability tensor for single crystal iron. However, as I read more, I find in many books it states for cubic crystal the tensor is actually a scalar, which means it is isotropic! Why does single crystal iron (body centre cubic) have anisotropic magnetic properties?

Answer (score 0):

Only an spherically symmetric system would have no anisotropy. In a cubic system there is [anisotropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetocrystalline_anisotropy) of 4th and higher orders.

Comment: Hi my2cts, by cubic i meant the crystal structure, rather than geometry